# Discord bot is not running

Tags: javascript, discord

I prepared a random image code for my discord bot but my discord bot is not running(no error just waiting)
Could you help?

codes i wrote :

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const settings = require('./settings.json');

var prefix = settings.prefix;

client.on('message', msg => {



np1 = "./images/1.gif"; np2 = "./images/2.gif"; np3 = "./images/3.gif"; np4 = "./images/4.gif"; np5 = "./images/5.gif"; np6 = "./images/6.gif"; np7 = "./images/7.gif"; np8 = "./images/8.gif"; np9 = "./images/9.gif"; np10 = "./images/10.gif"; np11 = "./images/11.gif"; np12 = "./images/12.gif";


if (msg.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + 'sgif' ) {
number = 12;
var random = Math.floor (Math.random() * (number - 7 + 4)) +5;
switch (random) {
case 1: message.channel.send ({ files: [np1] });
case 2: message.channel.send ({ files: [np2] });
case 3: message.channel.send ({ files: [np3] });
case 4: message.channel.send ({ files: [np4] });
case 5: message.channel.send ({ files: [np5] });
case 6: message.channel.send ({ files: [np6] });
case 7: message.channel.send ({ files: [np7] });
case 8: message.channel.send ({ files: [np8] });
case 9: message.channel.send ({ files: [np9] });
case 10: message.channel.send ({ files: [np10] });
case 11: message.channel.send ({ files: [np11] });
case 12: message.channel.send ({ files: [np12] });
      }
     }
});
```

(I put the gifs in the folder,12 gifs available)

Comment: What is the prefix and what is the message you are actually typing in Discord ? Are you sure you are at least getting in the `if` block ? Are you sure you properly connected your bot ? And please use loops

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you login with `client.login('TOKEN')` ?

and some update for your code :)

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const settings = require('./settings.json');

var prefix = settings.prefix;

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
    let imagePath = './images/'
    if (msg.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + 'sgif' ) {
    let randInt = String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1)
    // Create the attachment using MessageAttachment
    const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(`${imagePath}${randInt}`);
    // Send the attachment in the message channel with a content
    message.channel.send(`${message.author},`, attachment);
    }
});



client.login('TOKEN HERE')
```

Comment: thanks this method resolved the issue but nothing happens when I write sgif.

Comment: I'm going to deal with it now,thank you for your interest.